# Microsoft Identity Extending tables

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

ello

I am using Microsoft identity in my asp.net core project and i extended the table AspNetUsers by inherit from it a class called appicationUsers, after that i created many tables related to my own project and linked those table with the mentioned one (appicationUsers). when i migrate the DbContext to the database (sql server) two tables have been created (appicationUsers, AspNetUsers) and the relations created between ApplicationUsers and the rest of my tables not between AspNetUsers and them, also when i run the application and started to create users, they were loaded in AspNetUsers table.. so my question is ... how can my tables access to AspNetUsers table if no relation between them??

Answer (score 0):

in this case make a relation between ApplicationUsers  and AspNetUsers
like this inside ApplicationUsers entity:

```
public string IdentityUserId{get;set;}
public AspNetUsers IdentityUser{get;set;}
```

then update your database and fill IdentityUserId with a field which mutual between theses two tables like email or name etc.

then fix your create user code and add `aspnetusers.id` inside `applicationuser.IdentityUserId` while creating a new user.
after these actions you can access aspnetusers through other tables like this

```
context.Table.ApplicationUser.IdentityUser
```

or something like join in sql server

Comment: but i need to know is it normal behavior?? i think it should extend the table without creating a new one.

Comment: what do you mean by creating a new one ?

Comment: i mean can i extend the table AspNetUsers and add the new properties to it without adding a new table, which in my case applicationusers???

Comment: the standard approach is what your are doing (not adding fks in aspnetusers) even in some cases the aspnetusers table is in another database , but you still can add fks in aspnetusers